# Integral and scalar product function handles matlab

Tags: matlab

I need to compute this kind of integral

[image]

I defined the two `f(x,y)` and `g(x,y)` inside a single function

```
h = {@(x,y) f, @(x,y) g};
```

where `f` and `g` are formulas defined before. In this way I have a 1x2 cell and I want to compute the scalar product as

```
F = @(x,y) dot(h,E)
```

where `E` is a vector 2x1 and then integrate

```
int = integral2(F,a,b,c,d);
```

giving me this error

```
Undefined function 'conj' for input arguments of type 'cell'.

Error in dot (line 37)
        c = sum(conj(a).*b);

Error in tm_np>@(R,PHI)dot(e_n_even,E)

Error in integral2Calc>integral2t/tensor (line 228)
        Z = FUN(X,Y);  NFE = NFE + 1;

Error in integral2Calc>integral2t (line 55)
[Qsub,esub] = tensor(thetaL,thetaR,phiB,phiT);

Error in integral2Calc (line 9)
    [q,errbnd] = integral2t(fun,xmin,xmax,ymin,ymax,optionstruct);

Error in integral2 (line 106)
    Q = integral2Calc(fun,xmin,xmax,yminfun,ymaxfun,opstruct);
```

I don't understand why is giving me this error. As result of the integral I should have a 2x1 vector

Comment: Because `integral2` doesnt accept cells as input

Comment: What can I do ?

Comment: First give us a [mcve], but certainly you can not do what you want to do this way

Comment: is `E` always the same vector?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is the generation of your data. `integral2` accepts only functions that get `@(x,y)` as *vector* input and return the same size. in your case `h` is already not that, and `F` has no `@(x,y)` inputs (well, it has, but you decided not to pass them to `h`!!!).

```
 % sample data
 f=@(x,y)x.^2+y;
 g=@(x,y)y.^2+x+3;
 E=[3 1];
 % Create auxiliary fucntion
 mydot=@(x,y)(f(x,y).*E(1)+g(x,y).*E(2));
 % work
 int = integral2(mydot,0,3,1,5);
```

Comment: Perfect. I tried also in this way but was giving me other errors. I forgot variables inside. Like `mydot=@(x,y)(f.*E(1)+g.*E(2))`